# How to use pointerPressed method for particular image?

Tags: java-me, midp, j2mepolish, midp-2.0

Hi Friends,
             I have created one canvas form & on that i placed one image which is my button register. Now i am going to catch image touch events using pointerPressed method for only register image button. But how can i done this? can any one give me idea how to do this. How i can detect the user touches image of register using pointerPressed method. please help me friends. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Working with CustomItem will provide your needs.

Answer (score 0):

> I have created one canvas form

[Canvas](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Canvas.html) or [Form](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Form.html)? these are totally different objects and handling pointer events would be totally different in Canvas vs Form.

given your mention of *pointerPressed* I suspect you're talking about Canvas right?

**updated: For image drawn on Canvas (thanks for clarifying this btw), you need** to know coordinates of the area it occupies, then you just need to check if x and y coordinates passed to in *pointerPressed* are within area occupied by your image (these are horizontal and vertical location where the pointer was pressed, relative to the Canvas - check the API docs)

Comment: Yes i am talking about Canvas.